# Error on init method

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit


class Artist {

    let songName: String;
    let image: String;
    let artistName: String;
    let playURL: String;

    init(songName: String, artistName: String, image: String, playURL: String) {
        self.songName = songName;
        self.artistName = artistName;
        self.image = image;
        self.playURL = playURL;
    }

    class func getArtist() -> Array<Artist>{
        return [
            Artist(songName: "22", artistName: "Taylor Swift", image: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/AgFeZr5ptV8/maxresdefault.jpg", playURL: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgFeZr5ptV8"),
            Artist(songName: "You'll remember me", artistName: "Keith Urban", image: "http://d29ci68ykuu27r.cloudfront.net/product/Look-Inside/covers/5118691.jpg", playURL: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2en4ofkt1eo"),
            Artist(songName: "Cop Car", artistName: "Keith Urban", image: "http://nashvillegab.typepad.com/.a/6a00e552403d2f883301a5115b3dae970c-500wi", playURL: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJAe5miXN_Y"),
            Artist(songName: "Numb", artistName: "Linkin Park", image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/Linkin_Park_-_Numb_CD_cover.jpg", playURL: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU")];
    }


}
```

I am trying to initialise artists. I get an error pointing at the closing braces of the init method.

I am using the getArtist() to fetch artist for my UIViewController which  contains a table using :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    println("CENTER TABLE LOADED");
    artistItems = Artist.getArtist();
    println("SIZE OF THE ARTIST IS\(artistItems.count)");
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Comment: Post your compile error.

Comment: ... and fix the title and formatting while you're at it.

Comment: 0x1036b249f <+367>: movq   %r12, 0x28(%rsp)
    0x1036b24a4 <+372>: movq   %rax, 0x30(%rsp)
    0x1036b24a9 <+377>: callq  0x1036b2160               ; ChaseTV.Artist.init (ChaseTV.Artist.Type)(songName : Swift.String, artistName : Swift.String, image : Swift.String, playURL : Swift.String) -> ChaseTV.Artist at Artist.swift:19
    0x1036b24ae <+382>: addq   $0x108, %rsp
    0x1036b24b5 <+389>: popq   %rbx


This is the part pointing the error, I am new to Swift from a Java background so I am not used to debugging this type of error. It's all very confusing.

Comment: Can not reproduce - the code as given works fine. Post exact code and the line of error.

Comment: You don't need the semicolons in Swift.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet : Yes it's optional but I do it out of habit, coming from Java programming, and it helps better to understand at least the ending of my code.

Comment: But you don't do it consistently. Your return statement in `getArtist()` doesn't have a semicolon. And neither do your some of your other lines of code.

Comment: @ndmeiri My mistake, was used to having that being done by the IDE in Java. Added the semi-colons.

The weird thing is that the code now seems to run fine.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad you fixed the problem.

Comment: Your use of semicolons is still not consistent (see `super.viewDidLoad()`). You should simply avoid it (this example demonstrate clearly that it's not easy to be consistent) so that people reading your question see more idiomatic Swift code. No one using Swift in an idiomatic way will want semicolons here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restarted my laptop the code seems to work fine. Weird